# How implement an array of images in Python-opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I am programming a code that uses 30 images and I want to put those images in an array to resize them and then use them in other functions. I was trying some things but the second loop just shows me **one unique image resized 30 times**.

```
    import cv2 as cv
    import glob
    import numpy as np


    files = glob.glob ("C:/Users/Project/imgs/*.jpg")
    images = np.empty(len(files))

    #This loop reads images and show rgb images
    #Works OK
    for i in files:
        #print(myFile)
        images= cv.imread(i)
        cv.imshow('myFile'+str(i),images)


    new = []
    for i in range(30):
        new = cv.resize(images,(200,266))
        cv.imshow('imagen', new)

    cv.waitKey(0)
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Your resize loop needs to be inside the files loop. So indent everything below new = []

Comment: if you use list `new = []` then you have to use `new.append( ... )` to add element to list. And then you may use `new[-1]` to access last image on list - `cv.imshow('imagen', new[-1])`. Maybe use better name for list - ie. `all_images` instead of `new`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep many elements then first create empty list and next use `apppend()` to add element to list.

More or less

```
all_images = []

for name in files:
    #print(name)
    image = cv.imread(name)
    cv.imshow('myFile '+name, image) # you don't need `str()`
    all_images.append(image)


resized_images = []

for image in all_images:
    new = cv.resize(image, (200,266))
    cv.imshow('imagen', new)
    resized_images.append(new)
```

If you want to resize only first 30 images

```
for image in all_images[:30]:
```

Comment: thanks but the code just show me one resized image with that.

Comment: Now it works fine! Your solution was working but with ```cv.imshow('imagen', new)```we just put one name for all images and the program just shows a window with that name. The solution was to use a string that changes in the loop to assign the names for resized images.